# Minimalistic play() and pause() audio solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I found a little code snippet within another question, playing an mp3 just with jquery play() and pause():

```
<a href="#" rel="http://www.uscis.gov/files/nativedocuments/Track%2093.mp3"
class="play">Play</a>

<div class="pause">Stop</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    var source = $('.play').attr('rel');

    audioElement.setAttribute('src', source);
    //audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    audioElement.load()
    $.get();
    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    }, true);

    $('.play').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
    });


    $('.pause').click(function() {
    audioElement.pause();
    });
});
```

I get the audio source from the rel attribute of the "play"-link. Now I would like to add more audio links and make the source relative to their rel attributes.

I tried

```
var source = $(this).attr('rel');
```

and also .find() and .each(), but nothing worked so far. I've set up a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alani/VXRwN/) with two audio links, where only the first audio file will be played. (The fiddle links to an external script, which the client uses on his site, where only jquery 1.4.3 is loaded, but I guess it's possible anyway. I just don't want to use an audio player plugin, I aim for a minimalistic solution.)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your script to create one audio tag per container:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // For each container div
    $(".container").each(function() {
        // Create the HTML5 <audio> tag
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        // Find the play/pause buttons
        var $play = $(this).find(".play");
        var $pause = $(this).find(".pause");
        // Load the source from the play button
        var source = $play.attr('rel');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', source);
        $.get();
        // Play the sound when loaded
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function () {
            audioElement.play();
        }, true);        
        // When the user clicks on the play button, play the audio
        $play.click(function () {
            audioElement.play();
        });
        // When the user clicks on the pause button, pause it
        $pause.click(function () {
            audioElement.pause();
        });
    });
});
```

And updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sY7UT/

Comment: @Alani No problem, please mark as the answer if it works for you :)